# Unable to add membership types dropdown field to registration form

Tags: wordpress, civimember

I have created a Registration form using "Profiles", however when I add the membership types I get this message on the frontend: "Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type.". The field is type "Membership", the other fields are type "Contact" (as seen on the screenshoot) What am I missing, what is the approach for adding a membership type dropdown?
[image]

Comment: Can you please expand your question to include what this profile is for?  In CiviCRM, people sign up for memberships (even free ones), via contribution pages.

Comment: Essentially I created a profile called "Register" whose purpose is for people to register on the frontend for certain membership type.I added its civiCRM shortcode into a page with slug /register/
But when i add the top field "Membership Type (Membership)" (as seen on the screenshot) I get this message on the frontend "Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type.". I take it you cannot use Membership Types in such way, the only way is contribution pages?

Comment: @JoAnne This is a link to see what the reg form look like - https://drive.google.com/a/douglassdigital.com/file/d/0Bz1kxx0BuwdCQTZFeGZldUY4TUU/view?usp=sharing
This is with the message when Membership Types is on the top: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz1kxx0BuwdCZkYtR3BMSUNVZms/view?usp=sharing
All fields in the admin area: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz1kxx0BuwdCMTZObnBQT2hEeUE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way membership types can be used is via contribution pages